# Limit use of methods in built-in classes for programming assignments

Tags: python, overriding, built-in-types

I teach coding using Python, and in some assignments, it's desirable for students to implement functionality which is otherwise provided by built-in functions or methods of built-in classes. An example assignment is where I want students to write two functions - one called `insert_sorted()` that adds an element to the list so that the list remains sorted, and another called `insertion_sort()` which returns a new list and uses `insert_sorted()` for sorting.

My access to the students' code is through unit test cases, in which I can call these functions. The problem is that in the `insert_sorted()` function, students can use `list.sort()` method and in the `insertion_sorted()` function, they can use `sorted()` built-in function.

It's easy to override the built-in functions (which in this case can raise an exception with the message that their use is not allowed). I can also override objects and functions in built-in modules (e.g., I needed to prevent the use of `math.factorial()` function). But I cannot replace the method of a built-in type, like in the code below:

```
def error():
    raise Exception("Not allowed.")
list.sort = error
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    list.sort = error
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'
```

Is there a way to ban the use of specific methods in built-in classes?

Comment: I suggest you implement a simple regex test searching through the source code for "illegal" code use instead

Comment: How about subclassing list, overriding sort method and then replacing the builtin list with your custom (subclassed) one?

Comment: @randomir How exactly would you go about replacing `list`? Sure you can do `import builtins; builtins.list = MyCustomList`, but there are still list literals `[]` and builtin functions like `str.split` still return normal lists.

Comment: @randomir Your idea worked for one use case: the arguments to functions being tested can be objects of my custom class. If the list is expected to be mutated, then I can ensure in the unit test that I check the new value in that same object. If a new list is to be returned, then students can create a copy which is of the built-in type and use the banned methods.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, good point, not sure if list literal is replaceable, but for OP’s purposes maybe it is sufficient to pass in the custom list. Truly overriding the builtin list/sort/[] would probably break the standard library completely, so you don’t want to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[forbiddenfruit](https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/) might be able to help you:

> This project aims to help you reach heaven while writing tests, but it
>   may lead you to hell if used on production code.
>
> It basically allows you to patch built-in objects, declared in C
>   through python.

Here's an example:

```
from forbiddenfruit import curse

def broken_sort(self):
    print("NOT DOING ANYTHING!")
    return None

curse(list, "sort", broken_sort)

some_list = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
some_list.sort()
print(some_list)
```

It outputs:

```
NOT DOING ANYTHING!
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

It doesn't seem to be working reliably on my system though, and it outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

half of the time. Is this due to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)? I have no idea. :-/
The project might be worth a small investigation.